# QGIS 2.2.0 Creating all extension of MapInfo from a ArcMap ShapeFile

Tags: convert, mapinfo, qgis-2.2

I have a road centerline shapefile that I would like to create all files associated with a MapInfo file (.tab, .id, .map, .dat).  I've looked through the plugins and don't see a tool that helps with this process.

I'm very new to QGIS.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ogr2ogr as a commandline tool as suggested by user30184. This should essentially also be what QGIS uses underneath. If that feels too complex, use ogr2gui (http://www.ogr2gui.ca/).

As a last option MapInfo can also open SHP files, either directly or translate them using the built-in translator (cut-down version of FME).

Answer (score 0):

If you have the shapefile open in QGIS use menu Layer - Save as - Format: MapInfo TAB. If you prefer to use command line your tool is ogr2ogr http://gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html with the MapInfo driver http://gdal.org/drv_mitab.html and your command will be like

```
>org2ogr -f "MapInfo File" mapinfo_out.tab shapefile_in.shp
```

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I have done as you said, but it only creates the .tab file.  I need the additional files (.id, .map, .dat).  Any suggestion on how to create those?

Comment: I don't know why it does not work for you. I have no trouble at all.

\test\>ogr2ogr -f "MapInfo File" mapinfo.tab shape.shp

\test\>dir map*

mapinfo.dat

mapinfo.id

mapinfo.map

mapinfo.tab

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't write code, so I don't know what your response means.

Comment: It means that I used ogr2ogr program to do the conversion into .tab format. Then I made a directory list that shows that all .dat, .id, .map, and .tab files were created into the same place and therefore I have all that I need for opening the converted data with MapInfo.